# setInterval onclick of #fr_tab div and clear on click of anywhere in document

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this jquery code:

```
    $('#fr_tab').click(function() {
    $("#tab2").empty().html('<img src="images/loading.gif" />');
var handle = setInterval(function () {
    $('#tab2').load('fr_quests.php');
    }, 3000);   
    });

    $('body').click(function() {
        if (handle) {
            clearInterval(handle);
            handle = 0;
        }
    });
```

I was wondering how I can setIneterval when #fr_tab is clicked and how I can clear it if anywhere in the document has been clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `handle` variable is local to the first `function`.  Remove the `var` prefix to make it global is the quickest way to make it work, although definitely not the best.

Alternatively, to not use a global variable, then, if the code is in a $(document).ready(...) function then

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var handle
        $('#fr_tab').click(function() {
            $("#tab2").empty().html('<img src="images/loading.gif" />');
            handle = setInterval(function () {
                $('#tab2').load('fr_quests.php');
            }, 3000);   
        });

        $('body').click(function() {
            if (handle) {
                clearInterval(handle);
                handle = 0;
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

you will want to trigger on `$(document).not('#tab2').click(...`

Comment: hmm...put an alert('click triggered') inside the $('body').click function to see if the problem is the clear interval or the click trigger